# Why do I get the error "R graphics engine version 16 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer"

Tags: r, rstudio

I know this has been asked elsewhere but my query is different. I have installed the latest version of RStudio and I am getting the title error message (in the previous question the poster didn't have the latest version - I have tried re-posting there but no response). I have checked for new updates but am told I have latest version (not surprisingly - I only updated 2 days ago).

Having updated to R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt), nickname "Angel Food Cake" I now get the above error message. Plots appear in a new window but not in the plots tab within RStudio.

When  I run `rstudioapi::versionInfo()version` I get
[1] ‘2022.2.3.492’

Comment: 1) What OS are you using? 2) Go to  Tools>Global options>R Mark down and select "window" from "show output preview in" list. Also make sure to uncheck "Show output inline for all R Markdown documents" 3) Next, try running `options(device = "RStudioGD")`. If still not working, run `options("device")` and post the result here.

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 64-bit. I followed your instructions up to 3) and got the same error message.  Then in the last step I get  $device [1] "RStudioGD"

Comment: Now when I run the code, I no longer get any plot and instead the error message :Error in .Call("rs_createGD") : 
  C symbol name "rs_createGD" not in load table

Comment: Can you update your question with the Rstudio version please (`rstudioapi::versionInfo()$version`)

Comment: thanks for the update. Your Rstudio version is old -- grab the new version from https://posit.co/download/rstudio-desktop/ . You need to update and make sure you use the newly installed version

Answer (score 1):

Per user20650 's suggestion updating RStudio via   https://posit.co/download/rstudio-desktop/ solved the problem.